# SQL insertion query receive Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to run this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO answer_choice (id,text,question_id,is_correct)
VALUES (106189022,'11 Wall Street', true)
```

I receive:

```
 #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

how to fix this?

thanks,

Comment: If id is set to auto_increment then you don't need to mention in insert query

Comment: You didn't insert `question_id` value.

Comment: Also please add table definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert into 4 Columns:

```
-id
-text
-question:id
-is_correct
```

But use only 3 Values

```
-106189022
-11 Wall Street
-true
```

If you have an Field with AI, just dont use it within the INSERT INTO arguement